# Having trouble decrypting in C# something encrypted on iPhone using RSA

Tags: c#, iphone, rsa, encryption

I've spent two days on this so far and combed through every source at my disposal, so this is the last resort.

I have an X509 certificate whose public key I have stored in the iPhone's keychain (simulator only at this point). On the ASP.NET side, I've got the certificate in the cert store with a private key. When I encrypt a string on the iPhone and decrypt it on the server, I get a `CryptographicException` "Bad data." I tried the `Array.Reverse` suggested in the [`RSACryptoServiceProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.aspx) page on a longshot, but it did not help.

I have compared the base-64 strings on both sides and they're equal. I've compared the raw byte arrays after decoding and they too are equal. If I encrypt on the server using the public key, the byte array is different from the iPhone's version and readily decrypts using the private key. The raw plaintext string is 115 characters so it's within the 256-byte limitation of my 2048-bit key.

Here's the iPhone encryption method (pretty much verbatim from the [CryptoExercise sample app](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/CryptoExercise/listing15.html)'s `wrapSymmetricKey` method):

```
+ (NSData *)encrypt:(NSString *)plainText usingKey:(SecKeyRef)key error:(NSError **)err
{
    size_t cipherBufferSize = SecKeyGetBlockSize(key);
    uint8_t *cipherBuffer = NULL;
    cipherBuffer = malloc(cipherBufferSize * sizeof(uint8_t));
    memset((void *)cipherBuffer, 0x0, cipherBufferSize);
    NSData *plainTextBytes = [plainText dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    OSStatus status = SecKeyEncrypt(key, kSecPaddingNone,
                                (const uint8_t *)[plainTextBytes bytes], 
                                [plainTextBytes length], cipherBuffer, 
                                &cipherBufferSize);
    if (status == noErr)
    {
        NSData *encryptedBytes = [[[NSData alloc]
                    initWithBytes:(const void *)cipherBuffer 
                    length:cipherBufferSize] autorelease];
        if (cipherBuffer)
        {
            free(cipherBuffer);
        }
        NSLog(@"Encrypted text (%d bytes): %@",
                    [encryptedBytes length], [encryptedBytes description]);
        return encryptedBytes;
    }
    else
    {
        *err = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"errorDomain" code:status userInfo:nil];
        NSLog(@"encrypt:usingKey: Error: %d", status);
        return nil;
    }
}
```

And here's the server-side C# decryption method:

```
private string Decrypt(string cipherText)
{
    if (clientCert == null)
    {
        // Get certificate
        var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        foreach (var certificate in store.Certificates)
        {
            if (certificate.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.SimpleName, false) == CERT)
            {
                clientCert = certificate;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    using (var rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)clientCert.PrivateKey)
    {
        try
        {
            var encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
            var decryptedBytes = rsa.Decrypt(encryptedBytes, false);
            var plaintext = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedBytes);
            return plaintext;
        }
        catch (CryptographicException e)
        {
            throw(new ApplicationException("Unable to decrypt payload.", e));
        }
    }
}
```

My suspicion was that there was some encoding problems between the platforms. <strike>I know that one is big-endian and the other is little-endian but I don't know enough to say which is which or how to overcome the difference.</strike> Mac OS X, Windows, and the iPhone are all little-endian so that's not the problem.

<strike>New theory: if you set the OAEP padding Boolean to false, it defaults to PKCS#1 1.5 padding. `SecKey` only has `SecPadding` definitions of `PKCS1`, `PKCS1MD2`, `PKCS1MD5`, and `PKCS1SHA1`. Perhaps Microsoft's PKCS#1 1.5 != Apple's PKCS1 and so the padding is affecting the binary output of the encryption. I tried using `kSecPaddingPKCS1` with the `fOAEP` set to `false`and it still didn't work.</strike> Apparently, `kSecPaddingPKCS1` is [equivalent](http://lists.apple.com/archives/Apple-cdsa/2009/Jul/msg00027.html) to PKCS#1 1.5. Back to the drawing board on theories…

Other newly-tried theories:

1. Certificate on iPhone (.cer file) is not exactly the same as the PKCS#12 bundle on the server (.pfx file) and so it could never work. Installed .cer file in different cert store and server-encrypted string roundtripped just fine;
2. Conversion to base-64 and act of POSTing to server resulted in oddness that wasn't present in same class roundtrip so I first tried some URLEncoding/Decoding and then posted raw binary from iPhone, verified that it was equal, and got same bad data;
3. My original string was 125 bytes so I thought it might be truncating in UTF-8 (long shot) so I cropped it down to a 44-byte string with no result;
4. Looked back over the System.Cryptography library to make sure I was using an appropriate class and discovered `RSAPKCS1KeyExchangeDeformatter`, became elated at new prospects, and dejected when it behaved exactly the same.

**Success!**

It turned out that I had some cruft in my Keychain on the iPhone Simulator that was muddying the waters, so to speak. I deleted the Keychain DB at `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Library/Keychains/keychain-2-debug.db` to cause it to be re-created and it worked fine. Thank you for all of your help. Figures it would have been something simple but non-obvious. (Two things I learned: 1) uninstalling the app from the simulator does not clear its Keychain entries and 2) start absolutely fresh periodically.)

NOTE: The generic path for the keychain file is dependent on the iOS version: 
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/[version]/Library/Keychains/keychain-2-debug.db
e.g.,
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3/Library/Keychains/keychain-2-debug.db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well... the first step (as you say you have done) is to encrypt the same messages with the same initialization vectors using both the iPhone and the C# implementation. You should get the same output. You said you didn't, so there is a problem.

This means either:

- The iPhone implementation of RSA is incorrect.
- The .NET implementation of RSA is incorrect.
- The key files are different (or being interpreted differently).

I would suggest the first two are unlikely, however they are remotely possible.

You state: "Installed .cer file in different cert store and server-encrypted string roundtripped just fine"... this doesn't prove anything: all this proves is that given a particular random set of numbers you can encrypt/decrypt successfully on one platform. You are not guaranteeing that both platforms are seeing the same set of random numbers.

So I suggest you take it down to the lowest level possible here. Inspect the direct (byte array) inputs and outputs of the encryption on both platforms. If with the exact same (binary) inputs you don't get the same output, then you have a platform problem.  I think this is unlikely, so I'm guessing you will find that the IVs are being interpreted differently.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I can find nowhere in the .NET or Cocoa libraries where you can set an IV for RSA encryption or decryption. I thought IV applied only to symmetric algorithms.

I too would not presume to think that either 1 or 2 are possible, but I also cannot fathom that an X509 certificate's public key would be interpreted differently on the two platforms. But I took the cert from the phone and plopped it into the server and it was successful there so I don't know what to think.

I will look into the public key details within each platform to make sure that they're the same, <cont>

Comment: but I'm pretty sure that I shouldn't be surprised that the same public key might generate different output for the same input on different passes. That is the purpose of the PKCS#1 padding, something an Apple engineer confirmed: http://lists.apple.com/archives/apple-cdsa/2009/Jul/msg00032.html

Comment: Sorry - when I said the IV I was perhaps misusing the terminology - it's late here :) I meant basically the encryption key: the data you get from the ExportParameters method in .NET or the contents of your 'key' parameter on the iPhone.  I think it would be worth ensuring they are the same (excluding the private part of course).

Comment: I'm giving you the answer credit because you urged a fresh start.

Comment: My two cents here: IVs are used in block ciphers, not necessarily symmetric algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

this is my first answer on stackoverflow, so please forgive me if I do it wrong!

I can't give you a complete answer, however I had very similar issues when I tried to integrate with PHP - it seems that the format of Apple's certificate files is a little different from that which other software expects (including openssl).

Here's how I decrypt an encrypted signature in PHP - I actually extract the modulus and PK from the transmitted public key manually and use that for the RSA stuff, rather than trying to import the key:

```
// Public key format in hex (2 hex chars = 1 byte):
//30480241009b63495644db055437602b983f9a9e63d9af2540653ee91828483c7e302348760994e88097d223b048e42f561046c602405683524f00b4cd3eec7e67259c47e90203010001
//<IGNORE><--------------------------------------------- MODULUS --------------------------------------------------------------------------><??>< PK > 
// We're interested in the modulus and the public key.
// PK = Public key, probably 65537

// First, generate the sha1 of the hash string:
$sha1 = sha1($hashString,true);

// Unencode the user's public Key:
$pkstr = base64_decode($publicKey);
// Skip the <IGNORE> section:
$a = 4;
// Find the very last occurrence of \x02\x03 which seperates the modulus from the PK:
$d = strrpos($pkstr,"\x02\x03");
// If something went wrong, give up:
if ($a == false || $d == false) return false;
// Extract the modulus and public key:
$modulus = substr($pkstr,$a,($d-$a));
$pk = substr($pkstr,$d+2);

// 1) Take the $signature from the user
// 2) Decode it from base64 to binary
// 3) Convert the binary $pk and $modulus into (very large!) integers (stored in strings in PHP)
// 4) Run rsa_verify, from http://www.edsko.net/misc/rsa.php
$unencoded_signature = rsa_verify(base64_decode($signature), binary_to_number($pk), binary_to_number($modulus), "512");

//Finally, does the $sha1 we calculated match the $unencoded_signature (less any padding bytes on the end)?
return ($sha1 == substr($unencoded_signature,-20)); // SHA1 is only 20 bytes, whilst signature is longer than this.
```

The objective-c that generates this public key is:

```
NSData * data = [[SecKeyWrapper sharedWrapper] getPublicKeyBits];
[req addValue:[data base64Encoding] forHTTPHeaderField: @"X-Public-Key"];
data = [[SecKeyWrapper sharedWrapper] getSignatureBytes:[signatureData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[req addValue:[data base64Encoding] forHTTPHeaderField: @"X-Signature"];
```

Using SecKeyWrapper from Apple's example project CryptoExercise (you can view the file here: https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/CryptoExercise/listing15.html)

I hope this helps?

Comment: As Jon Grant suggested, I will inspect the public key bits themselves but the fact is that the iPhone is reading a X509 certificate bundled with the app (not generated on the phone itself) and I find it incredible that the phone would read the public key in differently. I'll settle this by checking the bytes, but I'm going to be awfully surprised if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

Will this help you ?

[Asymmetric Key Encryption w/ .NET & C#](http://www.csharpbydesign.com/2008/04/asymmetric-key-encryption-with.html)

- Sorry for the short post, time constraints and all.  Anyway, saw your Twitter request for help.. this shows how I did this with PHP and decrypted on .NET, simliar.  I notice your decrypt class is slightly diff than mine, so this article might help.

Comment: Sadly, OpenSSL is not available on the iPhone so it doesn't help me. But thanks for trying!

Comment: The point I was making was to try the decryption routine to match mine.  I found the 509Certificate2 was better.

Comment: That was my bad. In the code sample above, there's a private instance variable called "clientCert" that is of type X509Certificate2. I failed to include it in the listing. Sorry about that...

Answer (score -2):

I believe you've answered the question yourself. The problem most certainly lies within the endianness.

This is a possible way of writing two-way conversion methods:

```
short convert_short(short in)
{
 short out;
 char *p_in = (char *) &in;
 char *p_out = (char *) &out;
 p_out[0] = p_in[1];
 p_out[1] = p_in[0];  
 return out;
}

long convert_long(long in)
{
 long out;
 char *p_in = (char *) &in;
 char *p_out = (char *) &out;
 p_out[0] = p_in[3];
 p_out[1] = p_in[2];
 p_out[2] = p_in[1];
 p_out[3] = p_in[0];  
 return out;
}
```

This might be a good resource for you (other than wikipedia): http://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-big-and-little-endian-byte-order/

Comment: That's great to hear and thanks for the response! Forgive my ignorance, but how exactly would I make use of these conversion methods? I assume they're for on the iPhone so where would I plug it into my method?

Comment: Turns out that the endianness between the platforms is a relic of the PowerPC days. Mac OS X, being based on the x86 architecture, is little-endian--same as Windows. The iPhone, on the ARM architecture, is also little-endian as near as I can determine from searches.

Comment: Endianness wouldn't be a problem here, anyway. All of your operations involve raw bytes, not multi-byte numbers.